# Convert a circle into a spiral-shaped mesh via a Bezier curve?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I've been wondering, is possible to take a circle and turn it into a spiral-shaped mesh via a Bezier curve?

[image]

[image]

To elaborate I'm trying to make a creature with a spring-like tail and while I can make a spiral shape to form the basis of the tail, I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to connect the spiral to the rest of the body.

I figured it would be easiest to use a spiral-shaped Bezier curve and manipulate the top of the curve to create a connecting point to the main body.  The problem though is I don't know how to convert the Bezier curve into a mesh that would fit the connecting point of the body exactly.

[image]

Comment: Why not just use an Archimedean spiral curve set to Bezier?

Comment: what do you mean by turn it into a spiral? if you give it a Curve modifier for example?

Comment: LOL...everybody has a different question: mine is: what do you mean by via bezier curve? ....so looks like you should improve your question so we don't have to ask... ;)

Comment: You should consider separating the mesh (or a duplicate of the circle at the end of the mesh) at the point you want to make a tail, and then converting it to a curve, and using that as the bevel object to another spiral curve to define the tail, with a taper modifier to define the taper of the tail.  I spent about an hour writing an answer but it was bad, so I did not finish it as I'm clearly not skilled enough myself to explain this properly.  Hopefully this comment might be a place to start looking for more specific instructions though.